# How to give an array that lives in a state a unique ID using redux

Tags: javascript, arrays

So everytime my reduces is called, it should update the state. 
This works and it pushes the new information in a new arrayposition.

But now I want to add a unique Id for each new added arrayposition. 
The problem is that it changes the initial state from 0 to 1, but only once. I'd like it to increment to 2,3,4,5,....

```
import {GET_LOCATION} from '../actions/getLocation'
const initialState = {
    isLoaded: false,
    userLocation: [],
    error: null,
    time: null, 
    incident: null,
    Id: 0
}
function addNewLocation(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_LOCATION:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoaded: true,
                userLocation:[...state.userLocation, {
                    latitude: action.payload.position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: action.payload.position.coords.longitude,
                    city: action.payload.area.city,
                    country: action.payload.area.country,
                    time: action.payload.time, 
                    incident: action.payload.incident,
                    story: 'storytime',
                    userId: state.Id +1
                }],
                }
        default:
            return state;
            }
}
export default addNewLocation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import {GET_LOCATION} from '../actions/getLocation'
const initialState = {
    isLoaded: false,
    userLocation: [],
    error: null,
    time: null, 
    incident: null,
    Id: 0
}
function addNewLocation(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        const newId = state.Id + 1; // increment ID
        case GET_LOCATION:
            return {
                ...state,
                Id: newId, // update in state
                isLoaded: true,
                userLocation:[...state.userLocation, {
                    latitude: action.payload.position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: action.payload.position.coords.longitude,
                    city: action.payload.area.city,
                    country: action.payload.area.country,
                    time: action.payload.time, 
                    incident: action.payload.incident,
                    story: 'storytime',
                    userId: newId, // set to the userId
                }],
                }
        default:
            return state;
            }
}
export default addNewLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update `state.Id` as well:

```js
function addNewLocation(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_LOCATION:
            return {
                ...state,
                Id: state.Id + 1,
                isLoaded: true,
                userLocation:[...state.userLocation, {
                    latitude: action.payload.position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: action.payload.position.coords.longitude,
                    city: action.payload.area.city,
                    country: action.payload.area.country,
                    time: action.payload.time, 
                    incident: action.payload.incident,
                    story: 'storytime',
                    userId: state.Id +1
                }],
                }
        default:
            return state;
            }
}
```